# OnCompletion listener with two MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, listener

How do i use the OnCompletionListener for two mediaplayers playing at the same time?

The application allow users to play two media : Recorded track and Music track at the same time if one of them stops the other should stop too. 
I found solutions about how to apply on Completion Listener for single MediaPlayer.

My first approach was to declare two listener for each media :

```
mp0.setOnCompletionListener(cplmp0);

mp1.setOnCompletionListener(cplmp1);

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener cplmp0 = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer m) {


        mButtonListenOriginal.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_button_listen);

        mp1.stop();
        mp1.reset();
    }
}
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener cplmp1 = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer m) {

        mp0.stop();
        mp0.reset();
    }
}
```

Is this a good practice to do? Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways you dont need to check which player has been stopped, As you want to both player to be stop after any of the player completes playing.
So simply add common listener to both players.

```
    mp0.setOnCompletionListener(cplmp);
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(cplmp);
```

and stop both players

```
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener cplmp = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer m) {

        if (mp0 != null) {
            mp0.stop();
            mp0.reset();

        }
        if (mp1 != null) {
            mp1.stop();
            mp1.reset();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: some times mp0.getDuration()> mp1.getDuration() and opposite sometimes true ?!

Comment: Yes both players can have different duration. Can you please explain what exactly you want to accomplish? I guess stopping both players once any of player get finished playing. is what you wanted.? So it has nothing to do with the duration.

Comment: yes that what i want. I edited the solution and added"}:" and assigned the onCompletListener to the media. Thanks it working fine

Answer (score 0):

For a better readability, you can implement the listener to your class and set both players' listeners your class. Then in your overrided onCompletition method, you can make an if control for both of your players,

```
if(m == mp0) {
..
..
}
else if(m == mp1){
..
..
}
```

Comment: do you mean it is all about readability? and my example should perform well as yours?

Comment: Well you are using two listeners for your 2 media players while you can use one listener for both of your players.

Comment: I edited the code, controls will depend on players, not listener.